Chakra UI v.2 Unable to Interact with Window After Closing Modal Using useDisclosure
I'm encountering a problem when using multiple modals in a Chakra UI project. I rely on the useDisclosure hook to manage opening and closing modals across different components. The issue arises after I close a modal:
Persistent Overlay: After closing a modal, the overlay (chakra-portal) remains in the DOM, preventing interaction with the rest of the window. This happens across all modals in my project, regardless of their parent component.
Strict Mode Problems: When React.StrictMode is enabled, the problem becomes even more evident. The modal closes visually, but the overlay or focus trap seems to persist, blocking interaction.
Global Impact Across Modals: The issue isn't isolated to a specific modal. All modals across different components exhibit the same behavior. It feels like a conflict in Chakra's internal portal or focus trap handling.
Here’s a example how I use those modals.:
const Example = () => {
const { isOpen: isModalOpen, onOpen: onModalOpen, onClose: onModalClose } =
    useDisclosure();
const { isOpen: isDrawerOpen, onOpen: onDrawerOpen, onClose: onDrawerClose } =
    useDisclosure();

 return (
    <>
      {/* Trigger Buttons */}
  <Button onClick={onModalOpen}>Open Modal</Button>
  <Button onClick={onDrawerOpen}>Open Drawer</Button>

  {/* Modal */}
  <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={onModalClose}>
    <ModalOverlay />
    <ModalContent>
      <ModalHeader>Modal</ModalHeader>
      <ModalCloseButton />
      <ModalBody>Modal content goes here.</ModalBody>
    </ModalContent>
  </Modal>

  {/* Drawer */}
  <Drawer isOpen={isDrawerOpen} onClose={onDrawerClose}>
    <DrawerOverlay />
    <DrawerContent>
      <DrawerHeader>Drawer</DrawerHeader>
      <DrawerBody>Drawer content goes here.</DrawerBody>
    </DrawerContent>
  </Drawer>
</>
  );
}

My Goals:

Seamlessly manage multiple modals across components using Chakra UI's useDisclosure
Ensure overlays and focus traps are correctly removed when a modal is closed.
Retain StrictMode without modal behavior breaking.
Avoid manual portal cleanup hacks or workarounds

How can I resolve this issue and ensure smooth modal behavior across my application? Is there something I’m missing in Chakra UI's modal management or focus handling?
